# Add column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to know how can I add a column in a dataframe and fill it with the values of another dataframe. Example:

df1:

```
        Products          Materials
1         A                  Wood
```

df2:

```
         Price
Wood      1.02
```

I will get at the end:

df1:

```
     Products          Materials            Price
1       A                 Wood               1.02
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Series.map](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) method

```
df1['Price'] = df1['Materials'].map(df2['Price'])
```

**UPDATE:**

if your `df2` is a **Pandas.Series** use the folowing code:

```
df1['Price'] = df1['Materials'].map(df2)
```

Comment: If df2 has no column name what would I change ?

Comment: @hdatas, please check UPDATE

Comment: @hdatas, what is the output of `print(df1.dtypes)` and `print(df2.dtypes)`?

Comment: for Materials in df1 its int (wtf i'm checking my code) and float for df2

Comment: @hdatas, if you have any NaN's in the numerical column, its dtype will be upcasted to `float64`

Comment: It worked, the column was mixed with a previous line before. Thank you you're a genius !

Comment: @hdatas, glad I could help :)